# In an SSH configuration file, is there a way to split a "Host" directive over multiple lines?

Tags: ssh, openssh

Say I have a number of hosts in my SSH configuration that require the same set of options, but don't follow a pattern (so wildcard matching can't be used):

```
Host foo.com bar.com bin.com
```

Having all these hosts on one line is fine when there are only a couple, but once the line gets too long, it becomes hard to read.

I've attempted to use a backslash (a la shell syntax):

```
Host foo.com bar.com \
     bin.com
```

However this fails:

```
.ssh/config: line 1: Bad configuration option: bin.com
.ssh/config: terminating, 1 bad configuration options
```

Is there a way to split a single `Host` directive over multiple lines, to keep things readable?

Answer (score 3):

In this scenario, do `foo.com`, `bar.com`, and `bin.com` all route to the same `Hostname`?

I guess it depends what you are looking for, though. This doesn't consolidate things in the way I think you are looking for, but here is one option that might work for you. You can use Host "aliases" to define the hosts and then reference them later in your config file.

For example:

```
Host h1
Hostname foo.com

Host h2
Hostname bar.com

Host k1
Hostname bin.com

Host other
Hostname other.net

Host h* k* other
Username baz
IdentityFile qux.txt
```